# error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'. compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors

Tags: c++

I cannot figure out what's wrong. The error is on line 7, as I've commented out. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**error: expected unqualified-id before 'for'. 
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <math.h>

const char digit_ints[] = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'};
std::map<char,int> digit_map; 
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) // ERROR ON THIS LINE!!!!!!!
    digit_map.insert(std::pair<char,int>(digit_ints[i], i));


int str2Int(const std::string& S) { 
    int sz = S.size();
    if (sz == 0) { 
        std::cout << "str2Int() cannot take an empty string as a parameter." << std::endl;
        return -1;
    } else { 
        int sum(0);
        for (int j(0), k(sz - 1); j < sz; --k, ++j) { 
            if ((S[j]) < 0 || (S[j]) > 9) { 
                std::cout << "str2Int can only take strings with chars '0' through '9' as parameters." << std::endl;
                return -1;
            } else { 
                sum += digit_map[S[j]] * pow(10, k);
            }
        }

    }
    return sum;
} 


int main() { 

    std::cout << str2Int("3421");

    return 0

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What's this `for` loop doing outside of a function?

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) // ERROR ON THIS LINE!!!!!!!
    digit_map.insert(std::pair<char,int>(digit_ints[i], i));
```

That certainly *is* an error.  It's not contained inside any function.

Comment: How else am I supposed to get a map as a global variable? I need to use the map for my str2Int function and I don't want to instantiate it every time I call that function.

Comment: Put the for loop in a separate function such as Initialize() or something. Then call it separately when necessary.

Comment: Statements, such as your `for` statement, are not permitted outside the body of a function. In C, you'd have to put the loop inside a function and then call it explicitly -- or, for something simple like this, you can just move the `for` loop into the body of `main`. In C++, all the C solutions are available, or you can put the loop into a *constructor* which will be invoked automatically; to do that, you'll need to define a class and an object of that class type.